# How to share IKEv2 VPN connection via internet sharing

Tags: macbook-pro, network, vpn, sharing, internet-sharing

Im trying to share NordVpn from my Mac which is connected to ethernet. However when I do  select IKEv2 it won't show me the option to share that in internet sharing. Unfortunately NordVpn only supports IKEv2 and not L2TP